# Websocket Stompjs subscription sometime works

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

Here I have a code (backend SpringBoot, frontend Angular):

```js
constructor(private catDocumentBackendService: CatDocumentBackendService,
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private websocketService: WebSocketService,
            private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
            private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
            public dialog: MatDialog) {
  this.getNotes();
  this.stompClient = this.websocketService.getStompClient();

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.stompClient.connect(this.websocketService.getHeaders(), () => {this.subscribeStomp()});
}

subscribeStomp() {
    // Add a note
    this.addNoteSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/document/add', (data: { body: string; }) => {
      const body = JSON.parse(data.body);
      const newNote = body.body;
      this.notes$.pipe(
        concatMap(notes => {
          return of([...notes, newNote]);
        })
      ).subscribe(updatedNotes => {
        this.notes$ = of(updatedNotes);
      });
      console.log("Notified!");
      this.selectNote(newNote);

    }, (error: any) => {
      console.error('Erreur lors de la connexion au WebSocket:', error);
    });

    // Delete a note
    this.deleteNoteSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/document/delete', (data: { body: string; }) => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("DELETED");
      this.selectedNote = undefined;
    }, (error: any) => {
      console.error('Erreur lors de la connexion au WebSocket:', error);
    });

}

selectNote(note: Note) {
      this.selectedNote = note;
   
      this.noteSubscription = this.stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/document/' + this.selectedNote!.id + "/update", (data: {
        body: string;
      }) => {
        const note = JSON.parse(data.body);
        const updatedNote = note.body as Note;
        console.log(updatedNote);
        this.updateSelectedNoteInNotes(updatedNote);
      });
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I need to refresh several times my page until it works at some point. I don't have any error, it just doesn't subscribe.
And sometimes, when it subscribes, I just have to click on a note and it disconnects automatically. "Connection closed to http://localhost:8080/ws"

Is there a better way to do it?
I've tried to put the connect method in the constructor and in ngOnInit but it seems like in ngAfterViewInit is the less worse scenario.

Should I keep doing this with StompJS or should I use Socket.IO ?

Thanks for your help